# makeclothes not showing up in blender

Tags: makehuman

I have installed the makehuman blender tools and the only one that is showing up is makewalk I'm not sure if I stuck the tools in the wrong folder or what is going on someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

If you by "not showing up" mean that you were able to install and enable them in the user preferences but then don't find them in the toolshelf section in blender, this is because MakeTarget and MakeClothes end up on the properties panel, not the toolshelf. Press "n" in blender to show the properties panel.